# Problem in Notation Understanding

Tags: notation

$∃$ no $c$ s.t. $f\:'\left(x\right)=0\ \rightarrow \left(\frac{1}{cos^2x}\right)=0\:\forall \:c\subset \:x\:\in \:\left]0,\pi \right[$

I have confusion in the latter part- what I infer from it is, $c$ are the specific $x$ (thus being a subset of $x$) in the open interval of $\left(0,\pi \right)$. Am I right?

Comment: Terrible !!!!!!

Comment: I've edited to what I assume was the intended notation, but your confusion is understandable as this doesn't make sense unless we interpret real numbers as sets, which surely wasn't intended. What's the source of this notation?

Comment: @J.G. an old book of '70. It was in the Rolle's theorem section that for $f\:\left(x\right)=tanx% , there is no $f\:'\left(c\right)=0$. I think they were redundant (unnecessarily).

Comment: "There is no c such that ... for every c such that" ???? Impossible. I think it is more simply: There is no $c \in ]0, \pi[$ such that $f'(c)=0$. Fullstop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right.
The statement is saying that $c$ is some arbitrary subset of $x$
$x$ is in the interval $(0, \pi)$
So the first statement says that there exists no set of values $c$ which is a subset of $x$ such that...